# Is there a way to toggle a CSS animation?

Tags: javascript, css

I created an keyframe animation in CSS but I'd like to be able to toggle it.

I tried toggling it using JS classList.toggle like I would for a transition animation, but it simply removes the class without animating it out.

The only solution I found is to create two keyframe animation, one for "in" and other for "out". I was wondering if there's a easier way to toggle it?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ViniciusBortoletto/q13un4go/1/

HTML

```
<div class="button">Animate</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #212121;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box {
  height: 0vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #212121;

}

.boxAnimation {
  animation: boxAnimation 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes boxAnimation {
  0% {
  height: 0vh;
  }
  70% {
  height: 70vh;
  }
  100% {
  height: 60vh;
  }

}
```

JS

```
let button = document.querySelector('.button');
let box = document.querySelector('.box');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.classList.toggle('boxAnimation');
});
```

Comment: toggle it twice in a row

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS definition containing `:not(.boxAnimation)`, that reverses the animation:

```
.button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #212121;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box {
  height: 0vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #212121;
}
.box.boxAnimation{
  animation: boxAnimation 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.box:not(.boxAnimation){  
  animation: boxAnimation 1s ease-in-out backwards;
}

@keyframes boxAnimation {
  0% {
  height: 0vh;
  }
  70% {
  height: 70vh;
  }
  100% {
  height: 60vh;
  }

}
```

Note that this will animate the elements when they are created.

Answer (score 0):

```
.box.boxAnimation{
  animation: boxAnimation 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.box.boxAnimation.boxAnimationBackwards{  
  animation: boxAnimation 1s ease-in-out backwards;
}
```

In your JS you can test if .box already has .boxAnimation if yes add .boxAnimationBackwards and after 1s remove both classes; if no add .boxAnimation;